# how to make consultation with three tables in Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables that are the following **users**, **mapas**, **marcadores**

A **user** has several **mapas**

a **mapa** has several **marcadores**

What I'm trying to do is show the **marcadores** that belong to the **mapas** of the user who has logged in.

this are  the tables and relationship

[image]

This is the function in the controller that I am working on:

```
public function index()
{
    $mapas = Mapa::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    $marcadores = Marcador::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('mapa_id');
    return view('user.marcadores.index', compact('marcadores'));
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get all the **mapas** id first and then filter **marcadores** according to those id's. Try using the code below for that:

```
public function index()
{
    $mapas = Mapa::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $marcadores = Marcador::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->whereIn('mapa_id', $mapas)->get();
    return view('user.marcadores.index', compact('marcadores'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JOINS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins) for this. Try the next code (maybe the syntax is not the correct one, but take the idea):

```
public function index()
{
    $marks = DB::table('mapas')
             ->join('marcadores', 'marcadores.mapa_id', '=', 'mapas.id')
             ->where('mapas.user_id', auth()->user()->id)
             ->select('marcadores.*')
             ->orderBy('marcadores.id', 'DESC')
             ->get();                  

    return view('user.marcadores.index', compact('marks'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and Laravel standard way to do this is create a `hasManyThrough` relationship from `User` to `Marcadores`

**UserModel**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function marcadores()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Marcadores::class, Mapas::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $marcadores = auth()->user()->marcadores;
    return view('user.marcadores.index', ['marcadores' => $marcadores]);
}
```